# Generic type extending interface, cant access interface methods without warning

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, comparable

If I have a generic class,

```
public class Graph<K, V extends Comparable> {
     ...
 }
```

My understanding is that any object of type `V` is going be comparable since it extends the interface Comparable. Now I want to use a `HashMap<K, V>` inside my class. An object of type `V` inside my map should still be comparable. I declare a method:

```
public V getMin(HashMap<K, V> map, V zero) {
     V min = zero;
     for (V value : map.values()) {
         if (value.compareTo(min) < 0) {
            min = value;
         }
     }
     return min;
}
```

When compiling, I get  warning

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to compareTo(T) as a member of the raw type
Comparable

if (value.compareTo(min) < 0) {

where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in interface comprable
```

I interpret this warning as that the compiler is not sure whether `value` is comparable or not. Why not?  What is the problem here and how do I get around it?

Comment: Did you realize that the `Comparable` is in itself a generic type looking at the warning in the line your class is declared?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface is declared as raw. It should be used as

```
YourGenericInterfaceHere extends Comparable<YourGenericInterfaceHere>
```

or

```
YourGenericClassHere implements Comparable<YourGenericClassHere>
```

In generics, you will use it with `extends`:

```
YourGenericElement extends Comparable<YourGenericElement>
```

In short, you should declare your class as:

```
public class Graph<K, V extends Comparable<V>> {
    //rest of code...
}
```

Comment: for best results use `V extends Comparable<? super V>`

Answer (score 2):

`Comparable` is a generic type, so when declaring that the type parameter `V` extends `Comparator`, the interface should be parameterized:

```
public class Graph<K, V extends Comparable<V>> {
```

Comment: for best results use `V extends Comparable<? super V>`